# баг при правки вопроса/сообщения http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/576831/revisions

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/576831/revisions
В общем получилось так что при правки вопроса 2-мя пользователями. Я и @Alex и сохранили свои изменения и так в diff от alex мы не видим измений. Это есть ошибка нет защиты от одновременной отправки формы.

Comment: А в чем баг-то? @Alex сохранил свою версию через полторыминуты после вас (а не одновременно). Ему было показано предупреждение, что кто-то уже внес правку. Видимо он его проигнорировал. Дифф строится по версиям. Его версия аналогична вашей, поэтому изменений не видно.

Comment: @Nofate После сохранения я снова редактировал, обратите внимание на diff там нет не одной правки

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле дифф между версиями ненулевой. А защита от одновременной отправки есть, но она позволяет отправить одинаковые или почти одинаковые версии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Nofate на пробел могут отличаться.

Comment: @Nofate, они отличаются завершающим переводом строки. В версии Алекса его нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага, уже увидел, спасибо